# Jquery PHP Session

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Just wondering if someone could assist me on my latest issue. I'm very new at programming and really appreciate the help I get on here (so bear with me, we all have to start from somewhere!) :)

Basically I have this application and I've created a login for it and it verifies the information just fine and brings it onto the next page when you've successfully logged in perfectly.

What I'm having trouble understanding is starting up a PHP session with it? What I want to achieve at the end of this is to:

1. Start up a PHP session for the logged in user
2. Carry the users ID across the mini application so that it can later be inserted in another form and into the database without the user having to type it in themselves

My html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title>Find A Deal</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/findadeal/themes/deal.css" />
<style>
    #login-button {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }        
</style>
<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom3.js"></script>


</head>



<body>

<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Find A Deal</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    <?php

if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
session_start();
}

if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
/* User is logged in */
}


    ?>

        <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
        <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>  
        <a data-role="button" id="login-button" data-theme="b">Login</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>

<!--Newly rendered page after successful login!-->

<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h2>Find A Deal</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
    <h3></h3>
    <a href="#view" data-role="button" data-icon="search">View Deals</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/findadeal/login/newdeal.php" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add Deals</a>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript function creating the Ajax request Etc:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){ 
$('#login-button').on('click', function(){
    if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
        userObject.username = $('#username').val(); // Put username into the object
        userObject.password = $('#password').val(); // Put password into the object
        // Convert an userObject to a JSON string representation
        var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(userObject);
        // Send data to server through ajax call
        // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
        ajax.sendRequest({action : 'login', outputJSON : outputJSON});
    } else {
        alert('Please fill all nececery fields');
    }
});    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
if(userObject.username.length == 0){ // If username is not set (lets say after force page refresh) get us back to the login page
    $.mobile.changePage( "#login", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index  
}
$(this).find('[data-role="content"] h3').append('Welcome ' + userObject.username); // Change header with wellcome msg
//$("#index").trigger('pagecreate');
});

// This will be an ajax function set
var ajax = {
sendRequest:function(save_data){
    $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/findadeal/login/json2.php',
        data: save_data,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result == "true") {
                $.mobile.changePage( "#index", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index
            } else {
                alert('Login unsuccessful, please try again!'); // In case result is false throw an error
            }
            // This callback function will trigger on successful action
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });
}
}

// object to store username and password. 
var userObject = {
username : "",
password : ""
}
```

And finally this is my PHP file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$var1 = $_REQUEST['action']; 
$jsonObject = json_decode($_REQUEST['outputJSON']); // Decode JSON object into readable PHP object

$username = $jsonObject->{'username'}; // Get username from object
$password = $jsonObject->{'password'}; // Get password from object

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Conect to mysql, first parameter is location, second is mysql username and a third one is a mysql password
@mysql_select_db("findadeal") or die( "Unable to select database"); // Connect to database called test

$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

if ($num != 0) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
} 
else {
    echo "false";        
}


?>
```

If someone could help me out it'd be fantastic! I think I've the session started on the HTML side, and the javascript has the right elements to it, it's figuring it out on the PHP side is where I tend to lose myself a little. I'm trying to get the users id to be passed across the various forms of the application but is there a way this can be done without them ever having to insert it?

Comment: So all I have to do is just setting a session called username and im logged in? Not very secure. Also read something about the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and `mysql injection`. You wrote a toy for hackers if you didn't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two things you hope to accomplish

1. Start up a PHP session for the logged in user
2. Carry the users ID across the mini application so that it can later be inserted in another form and into the database without the user having to type it in themselves

By storing your data in the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) array you will have access to that data in every PHP script the user accesses.

In order to have access to the session array you must call `session_start();` before accessing the `$_SESSION` array.  Remember to only call [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) only once per PHP execution.  If [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) is called multiple times is will generate a warning or an error (I don't remember which)

You can check if the `$_SESSION` array is set to know if the session has been started

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    session_start();
}

if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
    /* User is logged in */
}
```

You might want to also take a look at this related question [PHP User Authentication with Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881642/php-user-authentication-with-sessions/14882113#14882113)

**ANSWER**:
@user2025934

> 1) A session_start(); must be called only once and at first to begin the
>   array and I add the mini php if statements above at the end of your
>   example to the top of all of my php/html files that I want to carry
>   the values across yes? With that in mind have I achieved what I need with the code I have
>   above? (I've edited it with your changes)

Yes, adding this code snippet will give you access to the `$_SESSION` array on any page you place it in.

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    session_start();
}
```

> 2) Also, is there a way I can test this to ensure its working? To ensure it's working I > assume I add an echo function to the second if statement in which the users username 
>   will be outputted? –

Echo`ng some output like below is one or many way to test if its working

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
    /* User is logged in */
    echo "It Works! - The user is logged in!";
}
```

Comment: Hi @BinaryAlchemist - Thanks for your response, it's really plainly presented so I'm finding it very clear to understand. Just so I can reiterate 1 or 2 points to make sure im on the right track.

A session_start(); must be called only once and at first to begin the array and I add the mini php if statements above at the end of your example to the top of all of my php/html files that I want to carry the values across yes? 

With that in mind have I achieved what I need with the code I have above? (I've edited it with your changes)

Also, is there a way I can test this to ensure its working?

Comment: Sorry I ran out of comment space there - to ensure it's working I assume I add an echo function to the second if statement in which the users username will be outputted?

Comment: I've answered your questions in the 'ANSWER' post above.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Just before you go, can you just look at my code above and make sure I've the PHP snippets inputted in the correct place? Or does it matter where they're placed? Is there a general practice in this area I should be following

Answer (score 1):

Put `session_start();` at the top of your PHP file. Then when they successfully log in, you can do this:

```
if ($num != 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

This will save the username to the session so you can then access the username of the user across your PHP pages for the duration of their session.

Comment: Hi @MattCain, I added the changes you said to make to my above code in the php file, could you assist me in one more query? When I went to run the code it said I've a parse error on line 64 - the closing </html> tag, have you any idea what I might have done wrong to get this?

Comment: @user2025934 You don't have a closing bracket for the if statement at the top of the HTML.

Comment: Thank you good sir! It loaded up just fine for me now. Should I have something included on the top of new pages now to hold the session variable as I navigate throughout the application or will it be held somewhere else? 
(I did say I was new at this! =/ )

Comment: @user2025934 You'll need to have `session_start();` at the top of any PHP files in which you want to work with sessions. Once you have saved a value to the `$_SESSION` array, it will persist until the end of the session (which is usually after a period of inactivity or having closed the browser).